# Prove (in)equivalency: (1) $\exists$ non-zero $z\in\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ such that $z^{t}=0$ for some $t$, (2) $\exists$ prime $p$ such that $p^2|n$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I need to prove the equivalency/inequivalency of two statements:

(1) There exists a $z \in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, $z\neq{0}$, with $z^{t} = 0$ for some $t \in \mathbb{N}$

(2) There exists a prime number $p$ with $p^{2}|n$.

Sadly, I don't have too much of an idea how to go about this. I've looked into Fermat's litte theorem which seems to be the key to this question but I can't figure it out.

Any hints where to go from there?

Comment: @PatrickStevens What does the notation "$z^t$" mean here? I know this notation only for exponentiation which is obviously not meant here.

Comment: @MartinRosenau: I'm the topic creator and as from what I've gathered, $z^{t}$ does indeed mean exponentiation.

Comment: @MartinRosenau Indeed, exponentiation. $z^t$ is defined for $z \in \mathbb{Z}_n$ and $t \in \mathbb{N}$ by $z^0 = 1$ and $z^{i+1} = z^i \times z \pmod n$; and $z^{-a}$ is the multiplicative inverse of $z^a$ if it exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $n$ is *square-free* (i.e., $n$ is not divisible by $p^2$ for any prime number $p$), then $n=p_1p_2\cdots p_k$ for some distinct prime natural numbers $p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_k$.  If $z\in\mathbb{Z}$ is such that $z^t\equiv 0\pmod{n}$ for some positive integer $t$, then $p_j\mid z^t$ for every $j=1,2,\ldots,k$, whence $p_j\mid z$ for every $j$.  Ergo, $n=p_1p_2\cdots p_k=\text{lcm}\left(p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_k\right)$ divides $z$, so that $z\equiv 0\pmod{n}$.

If $n$ is not square-free, then let $z:=\text{rad}(n)$, where the *radical* $\text{rad}(m)$ of a positive integer $m$ is given by $$\text{rad}(m):=p_1p_2\cdots p_k\,,\text{ where }m=p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2}\cdots p_k^{\alpha_k}\,,$$
for pairwise distinct prime natural numbers $p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_k$ and positive integers $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ldots,\alpha_k$.  It follows that $z\not\equiv0\pmod{n}$ and $z^t\equiv 0\pmod{n}$ for every integer $t\geq l$, where
$$l:=\max_{p\text{ prime}}\,v_p(n)\,.$$
Here, $v_p$ is the $p$-adic valuation for each prime natural number $p$.  Note that $l$ is the largest exponent such that there exists $z\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $z^t\not\equiv0\pmod{n}$ for every $t=0,1,2,\ldots,l-1$ and $z^l\equiv 0\pmod{n}$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $p^2\mid n$. Then let $z=\frac np+n\Bbb Z$ and $t=2$.

Suppose $n\mid z^t$ but $n\nmid z$. By the latter, there exists a prime $p$ dividing $n$ to a higher power than $z$, whereas $n\mid z^t$  implies that $p$ divides $z^t$ to at least the same power as it divides $n$. In particular, $p$ divides $z^t$ to a higher power than $z$, hence divides $z$. In follows that $p$ divides $n$ at least quadratic.